# Symfony access control

Tags: symfony, security, access-control

I want to authorize the access to only one ip to my API. But even if I write it in the access_control from my security.yml file, it seem to not work.

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/administration, role: ROLE_ADMIN}
    - { path: ^/api, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 527.0.2.1 }
```

The route I would like to block is all coming after ^/api/*

Thank for helping.

Comment: Do you have a reverse proxy?

Comment: The configuration could work if you put in a proper IP address

Comment: albert1 I do not use any proxy and I tried with 178.12.77 ip but no result to Nico Hass

Comment: 178.12.77 is not a valid IP neither is 527.0.2.1

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
access_control:
    #
    - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ips: [127.0.0.1, ::1] }
    - { path: ^/api, roles: ROLE_NO_ACCESS }
```

Replace **127.0.0.1** with your IP

Read Official doc [Symfony Matching access_control By IP](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/access_control.html#matching-access-control-by-ip)